# oracle 11g Grant on dbms_lock not persisting

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-11g, jdbc

I am using [oewizard](http://dominicgiles.com/simplebenchmark.html) from [swingbench](http://dominicgiles.com/swingbench.html) to create an order-entry like schema on oracle 11g. When I run the wizard I get the following errors:

```
ORA-01031: Cannot grant execute on dbms_lock to soe: Insufficient privilege
ORA-01031: Cannot GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$PARAMETER to SOE: Insufficient privilege
```

Now I am using the `SYSTEM` user as the DBA to log into the account from oewizard. Now my first question:

1. Does the `SYSTEM`user have `SYS_DBA`privilege from the beginning

I explicitly grant DBA privilege to SYSTEM from `sqlplus` (GRANT DBA to SYSTEM; Grant Succeeded) but while connecting via SYSTEM (the same user) through JDBC (oewizard's back end), I still get the same error. So my next question is:

2. When logged in from sqlplus (as SYSDBA), don't the grants assigned to a given user persist even after we exit sqlplus?
3. If so what would be the best way to assign GRANTs to a given user so that they persist?
4. Is there no way we can log in as SYSDBA via JDBC since when I tried it, it didn't allow me

Keen to hear from you

Answer (score 5):

From Oracle documentation-

> When you create an Oracle Database, the user SYSTEM is also automatically created and granted the DBA role.

```
SQL> conn system
Password:


SQL> select * from session_roles;

ROLE
------------------------------
CONNECT
RESOURCE
DBA

SQL> show user;
USER is "SYSTEM"

SQL> grant execute on dbms_lock to jay;
grant execute on dbms_lock to jay
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

The error has occurred because the SYSTEM user has no '`EXECUTE`' privilege with `GRANT` option on `DBMS_LOCK`.

```
SQL>conn / as sysdba

SQL> select * from user_tab_privs where grantee='SYSTEM' and table_NAME='DBMS_LOCK';

no rows selected
```

Also, the DBA role has no '`EXECUTE`' object privilege on `DBMS_LOCK` package.

```
SQL>  select * from role_tab_privs where role='DBA' and table_name='DBMS_LOCK';

no rows selected
```

In order to grant execute privilege, you need to connect as `SYSDBA` which connects to `SYS` schema, owner of `DBMS_LOCK`, or grant '`EXECUTE`' privilege with `GRANT` option to the user performing the grant.

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ sqlplus system as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue May 2 14:45:27 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> show user;
USER is "SYS"

SQL> grant execute on dbms_lock to jay;

Grant succeeded.
```

> When logged in from sqlplus (as SYSDBA), don't the grants assigned to a given user persist even after we exit sqlplus?

Yes, they persist.

> Is there no way we can log in as SYSDBA via JDBC since when I tried it, it didn't allow me.

Here is a sample connection string which works fine for me.

`Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/SID","sys as sysdba","password");`